# How to set FastAPI version to allow HTTP specifying version in accept header?

Tags: http, fastapi, api-versioning

I am working on a project that requires to version FastAPI endpoints. We want to version the endpoint through HTTP accept header, for example:

```
headers={'Accept': 'application/json;version=1.0.1'}, 
headers={'Accept': 'application/json;version=1.0.2'}
```

Setting up the api version like this seem not work:

```py
app = FastAPI(
        version=version,
        title="A title",
        description="Some description.",
    )
```

Does anyone know what else I need to do with this ?

Comment: I think `version` parameter is for docs only. Maybe try with [Response headers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers) for your responses.

Comment: Future readers should find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76014447/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well maybe the version in path url could be better

[sub apps docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/?h=sub+app#sub-applications-mounts)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
v1 = FastAPI()

@v1.get("/app/")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from api v1"}

v2 = FastAPI()

@v2.get("/app/")
def read_sub():
    return {"message": "Hello World from  api v2"}

app.mount("/api/v1", v1)
app.mount("/api/v2", v2)
```

You will see the auto docs for each app

localhost:8000/api/v1/docs

localhost:8000/api/v2/docs

But you always get the headers in request

```
from starlette.requests import Request

from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/hyper_mega_fast_service")
def fast_service(request: Request, ):

    aceept = request.headers.get('Accept')

    value = great_fuction_to_get_version_from_header(aceept)
    if value == '1.0.1': 
        "Do something"
        
    if value == '1.0.2': 
        "Do something"
```

Comment: Another approach  could be to add a  middleware to identify the version in header then redirect the request to service you want

Answer (score 5):

Try api versioning for fastapi web applications

## Installation

`pip install fastapi-versioning`

### Examples

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_versioning import VersionedFastAPI, version

app = FastAPI(title="My App")


@app.get("/greet")
@version(1, 0)
def greet_with_hello():
    return "Hello"


@app.get("/greet")
@version(1, 1)
def greet_with_hi():
    return "Hi"


app = VersionedFastAPI(app)
```

this will generate two endpoints:

```
/v1_0/greet
/v1_1/greet
```

as well as:

```
/docs
/v1_0/docs
/v1_1/docs
/v1_0/openapi.json
/v1_1/openapi.json
```

There's also the possibility of adding a set of additional endpoints that
redirect the most recent API version. To do that make the argument
`enable_latest` true:

```py
app = VersionedFastAPI(app, enable_latest=True)
```

this will generate the following additional endpoints:

```
/latest/greet
/latest/docs
/latest/openapi.json
```

In this example, `/latest` endpoints will reflect the same data as `/v1.1`.

Try it out:

```sh
pip install pipenv
pipenv install --dev
pipenv run uvicorn example.annotation.app:app
# pipenv run uvicorn example.folder_name.app:app
```

### Usage without minor version

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_versioning import VersionedFastAPI, version

app = FastAPI(title='My App')

@app.get('/greet')
@version(1)
def greet():
  return 'Hello'

@app.get('/greet')
@version(2)
def greet():
  return 'Hi'

app = VersionedFastAPI(app,
    version_format='{major}',
    prefix_format='/v{major}')
```

this will generate two endpoints:

```
/v1/greet
/v2/greet
```

as well as:

```
/docs
/v1/docs
/v2/docs
/v1/openapi.json
/v2/openapi.json
```

### Extra FastAPI constructor arguments

It's important to note that only the `title` from the original FastAPI will be
provided to the VersionedAPI app. If you have any middleware, event handlers
etc these arguments will also need to be provided to the VersionedAPI function
call, as in the example below

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi_versioning import VersionedFastAPI, version
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

app = FastAPI(
    title='My App',
    description='Greet uses with a nice message',
    middleware=[
        Middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key='mysecretkey')
    ]
)

@app.get('/greet')
@version(1)
def greet(request: Request):
    request.session['last_version_used'] = 1
    return 'Hello'

@app.get('/greet')
@version(2)
def greet(request: Request):
    request.session['last_version_used'] = 2
    return 'Hi'

@app.get('/version')
def last_version(request: Request):
    return f'Your last greeting was sent from version {request.session["last_version_used"]}'

app = VersionedFastAPI(app,
    version_format='{major}',
    prefix_format='/v{major}',
    description='Greet users with a nice message',
    middleware=[
        Middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key='mysecretkey')
    ]
)
```

Comment: There is also https://github.com/alexschimpf/fastapi-versionizer

Answer (score 0):

You can try my package https://github.com/modern-python/fast-version which adds versioning by Accept-header into FastAPI

Defining app and routes:

```py
import fastapi

from fast_version import VersionedAPIRouter, init_fastapi_versioning


VERSION_HEADER: str = "application/vnd.some.name+json"
ROUTER_OBJ = VersionedAPIRouter()


@ROUTER_OBJ.get("/test/")
async def test_get() -> dict:
    return {"version": (1, 0)}


@ROUTER_OBJ.get("/test/")
@ROUTER_OBJ.set_api_version((2, 0))
async def test_get_v2() -> dict:
    return {"version": (2, 0)}


app = fastapi.FastAPI()
app.include_router(ROUTER_OBJ)
init_fastapi_versioning(app=app, vendor_media_type=VERSION_HEADER)
```

Query examples:

```
# call 1.0 version
curl -X 'GET' 'https://test.ru/test/' -H 'accept: application/vnd.some.name+json; version=1.0'

curl -X 'GET' 'https://test.ru/test/' -H 'accept: application/vnd.some.name+json'

curl -X 'GET' 'https://test.ru/test/'

# call 2.0 version
curl -X 'GET' 'https://test.ru/test/' -H 'accept: application/vnd.some.name+json; version=2.0'
```