# FastAPI / uvicorn (or hypercorn): where is my root-path?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, hypercorn

Based on a few FastAPI tutorials, including this, I made a simple FastAPI app:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
app = FastAPI() # also tried FastAPI(root_path="/api/v1")

@app.get("/app")
def read_main(request: Request):
    return {"message": "Hello World", "root_path": request.scope.get("root_path")}
```

Which i want to have at a path other than root (e.g. /api/vi)...
Again based on most tutorials and common sense, I tried to start it with e.g.:

```
uvicorn main:app --root-path /api/v1
```

The service comes up ok (on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`), however, the `root-path` seems to be ignored: Any `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` gives:

```
message "Hello World"
root_path   "/api/v1"
```

and any `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1` gives:

```
detail  "Not Found"
```

I would expect the requests to produce the reverse outcomes... What is going on here?!?

I also tried initializing FastAPI with `FastAPI(root_path="/api/v1")` as well as switching to hypercorn without avail...

Details of the versions of apps (I might have tried a few others as well, though these should be the latest tried):

```
python                    3.9.7           hf930737_3_cpython    conda-forge
fastapi                   0.85.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
uvicorn                   0.20.0           py39h06a4308_0  
hypercorn                 0.14.3           py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
```

Comment: `root_path` does _not change the application prefix path_. It only instructs the swagger ui/openapi schema to prefix every request with a root path because _a proxy in between the client and the service_ strips away that part (i.e. the request is being mapped between the schemes _by a proxy_ in between). Use `api = APIRouter(prefix="/api/v1"), app.include_router(api)` for example if you want to have a prefix to your routes. You can also give the prefix when calling `include_router` to make the router independent of its mounting point (`include_router(api, prefix="/api/v1")` iirc.)

Comment: doesn't help, you still cant get the /docs endpoint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by @MatsLindh in the comments section, `root_path` (or `--root-path`) **does not** change your application's prefix path, but is rather designated for behind the proxy cases, where "you might need to use a proxy server like Traefik or Nginx with a configuration that adds an **extra** path prefix that is not seen by your application" (see the [relevant documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/)).

As described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#proxy-with-a-stripped-path-prefix):

> #### Proxy with a stripped path prefix
>
> Having a proxy with a stripped path prefix, in this case, means that you could declare a path at
> `/app` in your code, but then, you add a layer on top (the proxy) that
> would put your FastAPI application under a path like `/api/v1`.
>
> In this case, the original path `/app` would actually be served at
> `/api/v1/app`.
>
> Even though all your code is written assuming there's just `/app`.
>
> And the proxy would be "stripping" the path prefix on the fly before
> transmitting the request to Uvicorn, keep your application convinced
> that it is serving at `/app`, so that you don't have to update all
> your code to include the prefix `/api/v1`.
>
> Up to here, everything would work as normally.
>
> But then, when you open the integrated docs UI (the frontend), it
> would expect to get the OpenAPI schema at `/openapi.json`, instead of
> `/api/v1/openapi.json`.
>
> So, the frontend (that runs in the browser) would try to reach
> `/openapi.json` and wouldn't be able to get the OpenAPI schema (it would show "Failed to load API definition" error).
>
> Because we have a proxy with a path prefix of `/api/v1` for our app,
> the frontend needs to fetch the OpenAPI schema at
> `/api/v1/openapi.json`.   The docs UI would also need the OpenAPI
> schema to declare that this API server is located at `/api/v1` (behind
> the proxy).
>
> To achieve this, you can use the command line option `--root-path`:
>
> ```
>  uvicorn main:app --root-path /api/v1
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Alternatively, if you don't have a way to provide a command line
> option like `--root-path` or equivalent, you can set the `root_path`
> parameter when creating your FastAPI app:
>
> ```
> app = FastAPI(root_path="/api/v1")
> ```

### Option 1

Hence, in your case, since you are not using a proxy, but rather need to have a custom prefix for your API, you could instead use an [`APIRouter`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter), which allows you to define a `prefix` for the API routes (note that the `prefix` must not include a final `/`). You can either give the `prefix` when instantiating the `APIRouter` (e.g., `router = APIRouter(prefix='/api/v1')`) or using `.include_router()`, which, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#include-the-same-router-multiple-times-with-different-prefix), would allow you to include the same router multiple times with different prefix:

> You can also use `.include_router()` multiple times with the same
> router using different prefixes.
>
> This could be useful, for example, to expose the same API under
> different prefixes, e.g. `/api/v1` and `/api/latest`.
>
> This is an advanced usage that **you might not really need, but it's
> there in case you do**.

The `/app` endpoint in the example below can be accessed at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/app.

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.routing import APIRouter


router = APIRouter()


@router.get('/app')
def main():
    return 'Hello world!'


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router, prefix='/api/v1')
```

Once you have multiple versions of the API endpoints, you could use:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.routing import APIRouter


router_v1 = APIRouter()
router_v2 = APIRouter()


@router_v1.get('/app')
def main():
    return 'Hello world - v1'


@router_v2.get('/app')
def main():
    return 'Hello world - v2'


app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(router_v1, prefix='/api/v1')

app.include_router(router_v2, prefix='/api/v2')
app.include_router(router_v2, prefix='/latest')  # optional
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, one could also mount sub-application(s) with the desired `prefix`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) (see Option 3).

As described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/#technical-details-root_path):

> When you mount a sub-application as described above, FastAPI will take
> care of communicating the mount path for the sub-application using a
> mechanism from the ASGI specification called a `root_path`.
>
> That way, the sub-application will know to use that path prefix for
> the docs UI.
>
> And the sub-application could also have its own mounted
> sub-applications and everything would work correctly, because FastAPI
> handles all these `root_path`s automatically.

Hence, in the example given below, you can access the `/app` endpoint from the *main* app at http://127.0.0.1:8000/app and the `/app` endpoint from the *sub* app at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/app. Similarly, the Swagger UI autodocs can be accessed at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs and http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/docs, respectively.

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
subapi = FastAPI()


@app.get('/app')
def read_main():
    return {'message': 'Hello World from main app'}
    
 
@subapi.get('/app')
def read_sub():
    return {'message': 'Hello World from sub API'}


app.mount('/api/v1', subapi)
```